# How to rank some values in SQLite that resembles ROW_NUMBER window function in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have a table called t1 as follows:

[image]

And I want to get the ranking of the most popular sport in each country based on COUNT. So for Australia it is Swimming followed by Basketball, for France it is Soccer followed by Tennis, for Japan it is Sumo followed by Baseball.

We can make it into a table like this:

[image]

Or we can give a table of numbers it does not really matter.

Here is a version using PostgresSQL (it might be wrong):

```
SELECT Country,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
FROM t1
GROUP BY Country;
```

But when I tried using SQLite, it returns an error ' near "(": syntax error '. Does anyone know how to solve this problem using SQLite? I am a beginner in SQL and have tried searched the web but still have little clue. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The version of SQLite that you are using probably doesn't support window functions.  Can you upgrade to a more recent version?

Comment: Is there any other way without using window function in SQLite? I am trying not to use window function. @GordonLinoff

Comment: Just upgrade to a modern version of sqlite (3.25 or newer) and use `row_number()`.

Comment: I have just tried using sqlite 3.29 from https://sqliteonline.com/ but it still returns the same error. @Shawn

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using version 3.29 your query should be:

```
SELECT t.Country, t.Sport
FROM (
  SELECT Country, Sport,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rank
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY Country, Sport
) t
WHERE rank <= 2
ORDER BY Country, rank
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fHX54yv4SNUEJPiRcWy6nq/0).
Results:

```
| Country   | Sport      |
| --------- | ---------- |
| Australia | Swimming   |
| Australia | Basketball |
| France    | Soccer     |
| France    | Tennis     |
| Japan     | Sumo       |
| Japan     | Baseball   |
```